# Dismissing a RAID1

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I've a task in mind that sounds simple, but I'm not sure it would be possible to complete.
I'm dismissing a server, on which I've all partitions (boot partition and others!) mirrored as RAID1 through mdadm.

My idea would be to "dismantle" the raid, keep one of the two disks as "backup copy" of the server (possibly bootable and mountable at the need) and... discard the second copy and the rest of the hardware.

But reading here and there I'm confused on how to do it and if it will work as expected.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RAID is properly set up, the system should be able to start up with only one disk. That's basically what the RAID is for, to guard against disk failure. It doesn't matter if the disk failed by itself, or if someone actively got rid of it.

If you get rid of the rest of the machine as well, then you'll have to find a new machine to boot the system up from the remaining disk. That should work as long as the new system is similar enough to the old one. If you replace the disk on newer hardware, there's the risk that the old system will not have drivers for some of the hardware etc.

Though in any case, you should be able to attach the disk to another working system, restart the RAID in degraded mode, and copy any files you need.

If you only need a backup copy of some files, it might be more convenient to put them in e.g. a `tar` archive and store that somewhere.

If you're not looking for an extra copy of some files, but want to have a backup system to run some service, then *don't* get rid of the hardware, but keep the working system intact.

Comment: Nightly I ended up in changing plans. It's true that the idea of keeping an exact copy to boot it in the future may be more risky than the data loss itself. So I will probably make "selected" copies of data, and probably I will store them in new disks, better than in the original once that are 10 y.old. :)